# How can orthonormal vectors satisfy $\langle i|j\rangle=\delta_{ij}$?

Tags: textbook-and-exercises, nielsen-and-chuang, linear-algebra

In the book "Quantum Computation and Quantum Information" ("Mike and Ike") - chapter 2, page 66 - I have encountered the following paragraph:

[image]

If the vectors i and j are orthonormal, than their inner product should yield 0. But this paragraph claims otherwise. I was thinking of this over and over and failed to come up with the right explanation. What am I missing here?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: $\delta_{ij}$ is [Kronecker delta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_delta)

Comment: Understood. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When both vectors are equal and normalized $\langle 1 \vert 1 \rangle = 1$. This normalization is well defined since any inner product space is also a normed space $\Vert \vert i \rangle \Vert := \sqrt{\langle i \vert i \rangle}$. The notation $\delta_{ij}$ for the Kronecker delta captures this as well, and not only the fact that $\langle i \vert j \rangle = 0$ for $i\neq j$.

Comment: Understood. Thanks!